# React custom modal display modal content for milliseconds while refreshing page

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, modal-dialog, react-modal

I built a react custom modal. By clicking Open button showModal becomes true that makes the display block and Close button make the display none.

But I have noticed a bug while refreshing page the, content of modal shows on screen for milliseconds.

This is one of the important features of my app.

Here is the video link https://youtu.be/A6CUmSzwobY

and

`codepen link https://codepen.io/alligatorio/pen/aYzMKL?editors=0100`

I will be thankful if someone can point out the issue and how to solve it.

Comment: How about doing something like this: {this.state.show && <main> ... </main>} ? This ensures that it renders the content of main only if show is true.

Comment: Sorry, I meant {this.state.show && <modal> ... </modal>}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `return null` if the modal is closed. In this way, the modal is only added to the DomTree if it's supposed to be open.

```
const Modal = ({ handleClose, show, children }) => {

  // If the modal is closed, return null
  if (!show) {
    return null;
  }

  // Modal is open, render it
  return (
    <div className={'modal display-block'}>
      <section className='modal-main'>
        {children}
        <button
          onClick={handleClose}
        >
          Close
        </button>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/drojdr?editors=0111